# Set notification sound as default

Tags: android, audio, notifications, mp3, default

I'm using this code to set a sound as a notification message after I saved the sound:

---------------after saving---------------

```
 File k = new File("/sdcard/Bizzsound/", "b1.mp3");
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "sound1");                             
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
 values.put(AudioColumns.ARTIST, "artist");
 values.put(AudioColumns.IS_RINGTONE, true);
 values.put(AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
 values.put(AudioColumns.IS_ALARM, true);
 values.put(AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, false);
 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
 Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(menu.this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
                         newUri);
```

now i want to set the notification of sound message as default

thanks in advance

Comment: This should work but if the app your trying to test uses something else than default this wont work. It all comes down to manufacture implementation of apps.

Comment: the code works perfectly, but for message notification only works if the ringer is set to default

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the following

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,      uriObjectofYourAudioFile);
```

You would also have to give the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```